# Excel - roundup then subtotal?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, subtotal

A colleague has an array of values in "X4:X38".  Since these are in a table which may be filtered, she wants to use the subtotal function to sum them - but wants all of the values to be rounded up first.

```
={SUM(ROUNDUP(X4:X38,0))}
```

works perfectly well. However,

```
{SUBTOTAL(9,ROUNDUP(X4:X38,0))}
```

Generates a generic "The formula you typed contains an error" message.  I have tried various obvious things, like putting additional brackets around the "roundup" section, etc.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I will take a look shortly but I believe this might not be possible with pure formulas (unless you want to use a helper column, in that case it would probably be pretty easy). I recall personal experiences being frustrated with the limitations of `SUBTOTAL` in the past. It may be possible with VBA, however.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You **can** do this without a helper column by using this formula:

`=SUMPRODUCT(SUBTOTAL(2,OFFSET(X4:X38,ROW(X4:X38)-MIN(ROW(X4:X38)),0,1)),ROUNDUP(X4:X38,0))`

`OFFSET` effectively breaks the range down in to individual cells which are passed to `SUBTOTAL` function and that returns an array of 1 or 0 values based on whether each cell is visible after filter or not - this array is multiplied by the rounded values to give the overall sum of the rounded visible values.

Another way is to use `AGGREGATE` function like this

`=SUMPRODUCT(ROUNDUP(AGGREGATE(15,7,X4:X38,ROW(INDIRECT("1:"&SUBTOTAL(2,X4:X38)))),0))`

Given the complexity a helper column might be the preferable approach

Comment: Clever solution. Unfortunately it needs to use volatile functions so I agree the helper column might be better just to keep it simple. Still, great answer. +1

Comment: With the proviso that this is a volatile function as mentioned, this is a very clever answer and marked as answer.  Thanks.  Quite surprising that this functionality not included in SUBTOTAL - surely this can't be that unusual a situation?

Comment: @Statsanalyst I agree the `SUBTOTAL` function is severely lacking features. Typically if I want to do any sort of complex function with filtered data (only performing calculations on the non-hidden data), I just give in and use helper columns in conjunction with `SUBTOTAL` because as demonstrated, it is sometimes possible to do without helper columns but may be inefficient or overly complicated if your spreadsheet contains a large amount of data.

Answer (score 0):

After investigation, looks like this is not possible without helper column.

Add a helper column which rounds the individual values in column `X`, e.g. type the following formula into cell `Y4` and drag down to `Y38`:

```
= ROUNDUP(X4,0)
```

And then instead of

```
= SUBTOTAL(9,ROUNDUP(X4:X38,0))
```

use:

```
= SUBTOTAL(9,Y4:Y38)
```

Then if necessary you can just hide the helper column. Of course the helper column doesn't have to be column `Y`, it could be any column, e.g. a column far to the right of where the data ends.